Is Israel still "s'goolah" in the eyes of Hashem?
In the Torah 19:5 (Shemot), God says that on the condition that Israel keeps the covenant, Israel will be "s'goolah" (the most treasured) in God's eyes.
Is this a correct understanding?
What do we know about the current status of whether Israel has maintained the covenant? What do we know about the specifics of the condition - "v'atah im shamo'ah tish'me'ooh"? I assume it's too severe to say that should any member of Israel violate the covenant to even the smallest extent, Israel's "s'goolah" status would be terminated?
Which exact convenant, that Israel must keep, is God referencing in 19:5? The 10 commandments? (I don't believe these have been given just yet?)
Is there Talmudic discussion surrounding this question?
Thanks for helping me to understand this!

https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.36a.12?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

So, based on the words of Rabbi Meir, that, even if we violate Hashem's will, we are still His childeren, the Rashbam likewise explains.

@Shmuel thanks for the info! Does this answer the s'goolah question? Is it possible that Israel remains elevated as Hashem's children, even though Israel also lost the s'goolah status it once had?

That is the opinion of Rabbi Meir. We are always considered children of Hashem, even when we misbehave.

I'm specifically interested in the "s'goolah" status. I believe that being children of Hashem, and being "am s'goolah", are independent?
